# Python AES decryption struct TypeError

Tags: python, encryption, struct

I am working off this [link](https://www.novixys.com/blog/using-aes-encryption-decryption-python-pycrypto/#7_Decrypting_File_Using_AES) trying to decrypt an AES encrypted string.
I am unfamiliar with AES in python. The issue I am having is that on line 3 (as seen below) I am getting the following error...

The `decrypt(file)` method is being called with the below path to the text file that contains the encypted data.

I understand that `struct` is expecting an `int` value but I'm not sure how to go about correcting this.

I am running on a Debian VM hosted on a Macbook so I believe teh usage of `<` for littlendian is correct based on the Python struct docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

How can I correct this?

`msg = '/root/htb/boxes/chaos/mail/msg.txt'`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "en.py", line 60, in <module>
    decrypt(msg)
  File "en.py", line 39, in decrypt
    fsz = struct.unpack('<Q', fin.read(struct))
TypeError: an integer is required`

```
def decrypt(file):
    with open(file) as fin:
        fsz = struct.unpack('<Q', fin.read(struct))
        iv = fin.read(16)
        aes = AES.new(getKey(password), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

    with open(verfile, 'w') as fout:
        while True:
            data = fin.read(chunksize)
            n = len(data)
            if n == 0:
                break
            decd = aes.decrypt(data)
            print(decd).hexdigest()
            n = len(decd)
            if fsz > n:
                fout.write(decd)
            else:
                fout.write(decd[:fsz])
```

Comment: As an aside, consider using `cryptography` - `pycrypto` is not actively maintained and has a few serious known bugs including overflow potential

Comment: Sorry for the delay. 
@BradSolomon I'm not implementing this anywhere, it's just for a Hack the Box challenge. Duly noted though!

It's fixed now though. I'll add what was wrong below

Answer (score 0):

So I realised what was wrong. There were some more arguments missing from the offending line.
The correct code should read...

`fsz = struct.unpack('<Q', fin.read(struct.calcsize('<Q')))[0]`

Still got errors with the next line but the above modifcation solves the originally stated problem.